# hide modal using local storage site not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have bootstrap 4 modal pop up, which it appears automatically in my page, I have added a button don't show again Using localStorage() to save a “closed” state on modal so it doesn't show for that user again.

Here is what I have so far.

HTML

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="dont_show" class="btn-sm dont-show_again" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" >Dont show again</button>             
    </div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentLocation = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;

    if(currentLocation =="/create-movie"){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myModal").modal();
        })

    }else{

    }

     var dontShowId =document.getElementById('dont_show');
     dontShowId.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var isshow = localStorage.getItem('status');
        console.log(isshow);
          if (isshow == null) {
              localStorage.setItem('status', 'shown');
                console.log(isshow);
              // Show popup here
              $('#myModal').modal('show');
          } else if(isshow != null) {
             $('#myModal').modal('hide');
          }
     })

})
```

Unfortunately, after I click don't show again button it closes the modal but when I refresh the page it appears again.

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: you should make it shorter. i.e. [mcve], and you should see the problem

Comment: @appleapple I dont get it, what u want me to do :)

Comment: for example the `currentLocation` may be unrelated. (or it does?)

Comment: that is for showing the modal automatically, if you know what am doing  wrong u can help

Comment: yes you show the modal automatically, *regardless of condition*. and this is **the** problem. if you remove all codes related to `currentLocation`, it should be obvious. :(

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript code modal popup is shown irrespective of any condition. Although you are setting localStorage on click event of the button you never use that to check on your initial load. Here is the minimal simplified version of your code to get you started.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // onload decide baseed on localStorage
  var isshow = localStorage.getItem('status');
  var currentLocation = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
  if (currentLocation == "/create-movie" && isshow != 'shown')
    $('#dont_show').modal('show');

  // on click set localStorage
  var dontShowId = document.getElementById('dont_show');
  dontShowId.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (isshow == null)
      localStorage.setItem('status', 'shown');
  });

});
```

Hope this helps :)